# How to build Caffe framework XCode 6.2, iOS 8.3 environment

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, caffe

I am working on build caffe framework for ios, i used the Caffe master source and make files to build the framework for iOS.

I changed the OS target in CMake GUI config as "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk"

While run Xcode to build project i got the below error messages
/Users/Macpro_ios_v2/Caffe_iOS/src/caffe/common.cpp:1:10: 'glog/logging.h' file not found
"boost/thread.h" file not found
i included usr/local/include and opt/local/include to search paths in the build phase

while run the same xcode project for OSX, it works fine and generates the libs perfectly.  If i change the target for iphone OS i got above error.

Please help me to fix the above issuse. Please help how to configure  the make list in Caffe master for iphone.

I have caffe dylip, lib-a for OSX. Is it possible to link mac osx libaries in iOS project?

Comment: Track these issues for Caffe iOS dependents   

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/80

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/96

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/97

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/98

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/99

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/100

https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/issues/101

Comment: try this https://github.com/johndpope/ios-caffe-ObjectRecognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cloudVision,

You should install OpenCV2 from here before you compile the caffe-ios-sample:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html